# How to access HTML element attribute in jQuery JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to access the specific HTML element attribute and assign it to JSON property.

At first I get the JSON object from file and load it into **settings**. Then I go through the rows and create text inputs with various attributes.

Since I am using *iris* plugin, I am firing that right after. You can see that I am using changeElements function, where **iris-id** is being used (which works).

So the question is... why the **color** property in iris part is empty?

```
function startCorr(jsonFile) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', jsonFile, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            settings = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            $.each(settings, function(key, jsonRow) {
                $(sidePanel).append(createInput(key, jsonRow));
            });
            // iris
            $('.iris').iris({
                color: $(this).attr("iris-color"), // doesn't work
                width: 200,
                border: false,
                hide: false,
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    changeElements($(this).attr("iris-id"), ui);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Error getting JSON file");
        }
    };
    request.send();
}

function createInput(key, jsonRow) {
    input  = "<label>" + jsonRow.name + "<input type='text' class='iris' id='" + jsonRow.section + "' ";
    input += "iris-color='" + getColor(jsonRow.selectors[0]) + "' iris-id='" + key + "'>";
    input += "</label>"

    return input;
}

function getColor(selectorObject) {
    return $(selectorObject.selector).css(selectorObject.style);
}
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Global text",
    "section": "text-global",
    "input": "color",
    "selectors": [
      {
        "selector": ".button.special",
        "style": "background-color"
      },
      {
        "selector": ".button.notSoSpecial",
        "style": "color"
      }
    ],
    "areas": ["homepage", "detail", "category", "basket"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Text on hover",
    "section": "text-hover",
    "input": "color",
    "selectors": [
      {
        "selector": "#banner p",
        "style": "color"
      }
    ],
    "areas": ["homepage", "detail", "category", "basket"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to access data specific to an element to pass into the options of a plugin one very common approach is to initialize the plugin within a `$.each` loop. Within the loop `this` is the current element

```
$('.iris').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.iris({
    color: $el.attr("iris-color"), 
    width: 200,
    border: false,
    hide: false,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      changeElements($el.attr("iris-id"), ui);
    }
  });
});
```